# Linked lists on stack

Tags: c++

Usually, we define a struct or class node and whenever we have to add a new link to the linked list, we usually create a new node dynamically, right?

Like this:

```
node* temp = new node(x);
```

What if we want to create the new link on stack instead and not heap.
Is it done like this?

```
node temp(x);
```

Is this a safe enough practice? Because I see people creating a node on heap all the time and never on stack itself.

Now, when we delete a link, then, if we had created the list on stack, we don't have to use the delete/free operator/function, right? All we need to do is adjust the link pointers.

Is there any flaw in what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'd have to watch out for is the linking. If your `Node` looks like

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
}
```

If you make two nodes:

```
Node a{5, nullptr};
Node b{5, &a};
```

If for whatever reason `a` falls out of scope before `b` (it won't in the above example, but you could imagine a case), then `b` has a dangling reference.

When the nodes are declared on the heap, you can explicitly handle the order that links get inserted, removed, created, and destroyed.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah. I think I'm beginning to see why there's a standard way of doing it (on heap)
.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises if you return from a function but retain a reference to a node allocated as a local variable

Consider this (BAD EXAMPLE):

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    int v; 
    Node* next;
};

void b(Node*node){
    Node b{2,nullptr};
    node->next=&b;
}

void a(void){
    Node top{1,nullptr};
    b(&top);

    std::cout<<top.next->v<<std::endl;//<-- INVALID! Lifetime of b has ended.
}

int main(void){
    a();
    return 0;
}
```